# Trouble in handling item click of listview

Tags: android

m getting exception while taping on listView item..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adaptr, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    Times times = (Times)adaptr.getItemAtPosition(position);
    //Times times = (Times)MyXMLHandler.array.get(position);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(times.getDescription());
    builder.setTitle("Description");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Error.......

```
06-20 14:55:13.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 14:55:13.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 0
06-20 14:55:13.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
06-20 14:55:13.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
06-20 14:55:13.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:298)
06-20 14:55:13.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:740)
```

Comment: show full code with `MyAdapter` class.

Comment: MyAdapter class code required..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to fill data in your **adapter**, Your **adapter is empty**..

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item);
```

Fill with some data like `String[]` or `ArrayList`...

**UPDATE:**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adaptr, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    Times times = MyXMLHandler.array.get(position);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(times.getDescription());
    builder.setTitle("Description");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            finish();
        }
    });
   builder.show();
}
```

Comment: thnx m getting value but dialog alertDialog iz not commming

Comment: Look at my answer, I updated code, you have to add builder.show(); line, Also If you found this answer is helpful to you then accept as a correct answer, by click on right symbol left side of my answer, This will help you and other user in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You have Error here

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item);
```

Your adapter is Empty.

Comment: how to check adapter empty or not?

Comment: public int getCount() {
  return MyXMLHandler.array.size();
 }
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {
   
  LinearLayout layout = null;
  TextView textView = null;
  Times times = MyXMLHandler.array.get(position);
  if(convertView == null){
   LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getLayoutInflater();
   layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
  }else{
   layout = (LinearLayout)convertView;}
  textView =(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.listViewText);
  textView.setText(times.getTitle());   
  return layout;}